# Define custom linestyles in Octave for use on multiple figures

Tags: octave, linestyle

I'd like to define line styles in Octave (like in gnuplot) for further usage:

I was thinking about something like that:

```
styles = {['color',[.5 .2 .8],'--', 'linewidth', 1.25], ['or', markersize, 4], 
['-sb', markersize, 2]}

plot (x,y, styles{1})
plot (x,y, styles{2})
```

and so on. But such a thing didn't work. Does someone have any suggestions how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look, what MATLAB does and copy the ideas: You can use [Comma-Separated Lists as Function Call Arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html#br2js35-13). Actually, there's an example describing exactly, what you want to achieve. Nevertheless, to get this working as you'd like to, you also have to "disassemble" the [`LineSpec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html) properly. Please see the following code snippet to get the solution for the examples given by you.

```matlab
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 50);

% styles = {['color',[.5 .2 .8],'--', 'linewidth', 1.25], ['or', markersize, 4], ['-sb', markersize, 2]}

styles = {
  {'Color', [.5 .2 .8], 'LineStyle', '--', 'LineWidth', 1.25}, ...
  {'Color', 'r', 'Marker', 'o', 'MarkerSize', 4}, ...
  {'Color', 'b', 'LineStyle', '-', 'Marker', 's', 'MarkerSize', 2} ...
};

figure(1);
hold on;

for ii = 1:numel(styles)
  plot(x, sin(x + ii * pi/4), styles{ii}{:});
end

hold off;

legend();
```

And, here is an exemplary output:

[image: Exemplary output]